# How can I add a local image on a map in leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet

I want to put a local image onto my leaflet map in R like this (I put the image manually in paint):

[image]
I tried this based on the example in `?mapview::addLogo`:

```
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)

cities <- read.csv(textConnection("
    City,Lat,Long,Pop
                                      Boston,42.3601,-71.0589,645966
                                      Hartford,41.7627,-72.6743,125017
                                      New York City,40.7127,-74.0059,8406000
                                      Philadelphia,39.9500,-75.1667,1553000
                                      Pittsburgh,40.4397,-79.9764,305841
                                      Providence,41.8236,-71.4222,177994
                                      "))

img1 <- system.file("img1.png", package = "png")

leaflet(cities) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircles(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 1,
               radius = ~sqrt(Pop) * 30, popup = ~City)%>%
    addLogo(img1, src = "local", position = "bottomright", alpha = 0.3)
```

but it didn't add the image to the map:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You're getting confused (and with good reason, it's a confusing help example) by the example in the help for `?addLogo`. All `addLogo` needs is the path to the image. The call to `system.file` used in that help example just returns the path to a sample image included in the `png` package that was used for example purposes. If you already know the path to your image, you can just supply that.

Therefore, assuming that your image is named `img1.png` and is in the current working directory, you can just do this:

```
leaflet(cities) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircles(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat, weight = 1,
               radius = ~sqrt(Pop) * 30, popup = ~City)%>%
    addLogo("img1.png", src = "local",position = "bottomright", alpha = 0.3)
```

Comment: Error: object 'addLogo' not found